# Question about connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

The subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the one component is rational and the other is irrational is connected or disconected?

$E = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{I}) \text{ or } ( x \in \mathbb{I} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{Q} ) \}$ with subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set $E$ is connected?

I think that thus subset is disconected, but I don't know how show

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you add more context?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku $E = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{I}) \text{ or } ( x \in \mathbb{I} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{Q} ) \}$ with subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set $E$ is connected?

Comment: Think of the line $x=y$. Also, think of the half-planes above and below it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin then if define $X$ the half plane that is above the line and $Y$ the half plane of the lower part of the line, then $X$ and $Y$ are separated, since $\overline{X} \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $\overline{Y} \cap X = \emptyset$ then $E$ is disconnected, I'm good?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One just use definition of connectives. That is, if $E$ were NOT connected then one can find two open, not empty sets, say $X$ and $Y$ such that $E=X\cup{Y}$.
Since $X$ is open it contains a ball, say with radius $r>0$. But in this ball, there are points which are not in E ... .

Comment: With this definition of "connected", the set $\{0\} \cup \{1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected...

Comment: Why do you think that  $\{0\}$ is open in $R$?

Comment: I think that $\{0\}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. According to the definition of connectednes you give, the set $S=\{0\} \cup \{1\}$ could be split into two non-empty open sets. Which is not possible.

Comment: I think I said: "... if E is NOT connected then ..."

Comment: I apply your definition: $S$ is not connected, so one can find two open, non empty sets $X$ and $Y$, such that $S=X \cup Y$.